# Can the level attribute of xsl:number be set from an variable value?

Tags: xslt-2.0

Example:

```
<!-- suppose $vLevel is a variable of type xs:string, with value 'multiple' -->

<xsl:number count="li" level="{$vLevel}" />
```

This fails, as expected, since after looking further this needs to be one of `single`, `multiple`, or `any`.

But, is there a way to build the xsl:number instruction dynamically?  At the moment, I am checking `$vLevel`, e.g.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$vLevel = 'multiple'">
        <xsl:number count="li" level="multiple" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$vLevel = 'any'">
        <xsl:number count="li" level="any" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:number count="li" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This is fine, except I am using other attributes besides `count`, and would like to avoid repeating the attributes if possible.

*Edit*:

The input document can contain an HTML-like list, with arbitrary nesting:

```
<ol style="numbering-format : 1.; numbering-level : single;">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <ol style="numbering-format : 1.; numbering-level : multiple;">
        <li>item 2.1</li>
        <li>item 2.2</li>
    </ol>
 </ol>
```

The `numbering-format` and `numbering-level` are not standard CSS style properties.  But, I am transforming this into another XML format (Adobe XFA).

The idea is the author can declare the type of numbering, making `$vLevel` a local variable, not global, derived from the input source.

Comment: Where are you setting `$vLevel`, as a global variable or parameter? In that case, but only with XSLT 3, you could convert it to a static variable or parameter e.g. `<xsl:param name="vLevel" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'single'"/>` and then use a so called shadow-attribute `<xsl:number _level="{$vLevel}" ../>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen `$vLevel` is a local variable.  I've added more details in the question.

Comment: I am not sure there is a way other than running two steps where you first generate the XSLT with the wanted levels and then run it. For what its worth, there is currently some community effort to create XSLT 4, on xmlcom.slack.com there is a dedicated channel for discussions, I have asked there whether the current restriction can be easily lifted to allow `level="{$vLevel}"`, perhaps your answer creates a fruitful improvement in the future.